# Open XML - Word: Create tab with leading dots (.NET 3.5 - C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to create tab with leading dots like this in OpenXML for Word.

[image]

Do you know how to do it?
This is what I found:
http://officeopenxml.com/WPtab.php
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tabchar.aspx
but I don't know how to translate to C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I create this ParagraphProperties:

```
ParagraphProperties pProperties = new ParagraphProperties( 
     new Tabs(
             new TabStop() { Val = TabStopValues.Right, Position = 4320, Leader = TabStopLeaderCharValues.Dot }
     )
);
```

and added to `Paragraph` and it works.